# Exception: The starting row of the range is too small. | Google Apps Script error

Tags: html, google-apps-script

When I test on the HTML page, it has no response after entering ID Number and clicking search button.

Could anyone help me how to change the codes to make it work?

Below codes are trying to display a HTML page for users to input ID Number and then get the latest row of related data from Google Sheet. Thank you.

index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-2">  
        <label for="idNum">ID Number</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="idNum">
        <output id="rnum"></output>
      </div>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info" id="searchbtn">Search Profile</button>
   </div>
<script>
    document.getElementById("searchbtn").addEventListener("click", searchProfile);
   function searchProfile(){
     var appProfile = document.getElementById("idNum").value;
     if(appProfile.length === 6){
     google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateProfile).updateIdNum(appProfile);
     } 
     //else{
     //alert("invalid Profile Number");
     }   
   function updateProfile(returnData){
      document.getElementById("rnum").value = returnData[1];
   }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Apps Script:

```js
function doGet(e){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index");
}

function updateIdNum(appProfile){
  //  var appProfile = "101018"

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Results");

let data = ws.getRange(2, 1, ws.getLastRow(), 1).getValues() // retrieve the first column, but not the header! and remove all possible empty cells
  .flat() // transform the array from [[...],[...]] to [...,...]
  .filter(cell => cell != '') // remove empty rows
let myPnum = data.indexOf(appProfile) // search your ID
if(myPnum == -1) {
  // then the ID doesnt exist in the sheet, deal with it
} else {
  // you can retrieve the corresponding row
  let fullRow = ws.getRange(myPnum + 2, 1, 1, ws.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  // do whatever you need to do...
}

  if (myPnum > -1){
    return dataRow[0];
  } else {
    Logger.log("unknown")
    //return "unavailable";
  } 
}


function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
  .createMenu('Custom Menu')
  .addItem('Show sidebar', 'showSidebar')
  .addToUi();
}

function showSidebar() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
  .setTitle('My custom sidebar')
  .setWidth(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
  .showSidebar(html);
}
```

Google Sheet - Sheet (Result) look like:

```html
ID Number | First Name | Last Name|
101018    | John       | Doe      |
101011    | Jane       | Doe      |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var myPnum = dJoin.indexOf(appProfile);
var dataRow = ws.getRange(myPnum + 1, 1, 1, ws.getLastColumn()).getValues();
```

You don't handle the case when `appProfile` is not in the `dJoin` array.

When this happens, the `indexOf` will return -1. So `myPnum` will equals -1. And so the first parameter of `getRange` will be -1 + 1 = 0 which is incorrect for Apps Script, it has to be 1 (= first line) or higher.

**Retrieve the ID properly from your sheet**

`myPnum + 2` will not help you. The error will disappear but the problem is not there. The problem is how you retrieve the values from the sheet. You should not do `join().split()`.

To retrieve all the IDs already present in your sheet, you need to do

```
let data = ws.getRange(2, 1, ws.getLastRow(), 1).getValues() // retrieve the first column, but not the header! and remove all possible empty cells
  .flat() // transform the array from [[...],[...]] to [...,...]
  .filter(cell => cell != '') // remove empty rows
let myPnum = data.indexOf(appProfile) // search your ID
if(myPnum == -1) {
  // then the ID doesnt exist in the sheet, deal with it
} else {
  // you can retrieve the corresponding row
  let fullRow = ws.getRange(myPnum + 2, 1, 1, ws.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  // do whatever you need to do...
}
```

Comment: Hello ValLeNain, as I understand I change the code as below. It seems works
var dataRow = ws.getRange(myPnum + 2, 1, 1, ws.getLastColumn()).getValues();

Comment: I am new to apps script, may I know how can I deploy HTML within apps script to my server as a "real" html please?

Comment: please read the last part I wrote, it will explain how you should retrieve the values. Also, I don't understand your last comment

Comment: Hello ValLeNain, I updated the post and renewed the code, mainly I added "function doGet" for running HTML. However HTML testing page open successfully but search function not working. Any thoughts?

Comment: First, I don't undestand what is the `doGet` for since you're in a sidebar. Second, what is not working with the search ? `updateIdNum` is not called ? Or the success handler is not called ? Try to get some logs from both the javascript (e.g. the code running in index.html) and from the Apps Script

Comment: If I do without doGet function, test deployments is having error said "cannot find doGet".
If I do doGet function, test deployments can open succssfully with an input box and a search buttonm
For Apps script log:
 Execution starts,
Unknown,
Execution completes

Comment: There would be a lot to say but I suggest your read the guide for developers related to Google Sheets. Depending on what you want to do (custom menu, deployed webapp, Workspace addon...), it's not the same code and not the same way to package it (but it's always Apps Script): https://developers.google.com/sheets.
Last thing: if you can see "Unknown" in the logs, it means that the Apps Script code is called and that the appProfile is not found

Comment: @lawrencemaMa I'd suggest you to post a new question and accept this answer, since your original issue `Exception: The starting row of the range is too small` was solved, and you are asking a completely different question now.